# Access docmd.transferspreadsheet specific cells

Tags: ms-access, vba

if anyone could give me some advice on how to select specific cells it would be appreciated. I can get the command to work with a range, see  "A1:A50" in the current code. Any time i've tried to use a list, it hasn't worked.

Looking for the following cells to import: A1, C16, C18, F16, F18

```
Public Sub ImportExcelSpreadsheet(fileName As String, tableName As String)
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, tableName, fileName, False, "A1:A50"
End Sub
```

Comment: Can't use TransferSpreadsheet for non-contiguous cells, that's why must be a Range. Use Excel automation code. Or if the sheet is simple enough, set a link.

Comment: Hey June, thank you for the feedback! I avoided adding too much background to keep the question clear but maybe some would help.

I've got an access database with a table `tbl_jobList`. There are over 900 excel files (only 1 sheet) that have data populated with the exact same template. 

My goal was to import the specific list of cells from each excel file as a row into the access table. Since transferspreadsheet will not work, is there an alternative you could suggest? I do not want to link over 900 sheets.

Comment: Excel automation. VBA declares, opens, and manipulates Excel objects. Reivew http://www.accessmvp.com/KDSnell/EXCEL_Import.htm#WriteFileRst